# One host, two subdomains, multiple (dockered) web-services with SSL

Tags: nginx, ssl, ssl-certificate, virtualhost, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have a centos 7 server with two subdomains (cloud.myserver.com, services.myserver.com) which I want to host different services with: Seafile, Gitea, Redmine, ... . cloud.myserver.com points only to seafile, which runs in a docker container.

The seafile server works as it should using the nginx server within the container. It fetches its SSL certificate on its own using Letsencrypt.

services.myserver.com is supposed to point to my other services either using different ports (e.g. Gitea on 4100 and Redmine on 4200) or subfolders (services.myserver.com/gitea and services.myserver.com/redmine).

Now this is basically where I am lost! I can configure the docker containers for Gitea and Redmine to appear at a certain port at the host, but then I do not have SSL. As far as I have understood I need an nginx as proxy, which then provides my sites. But how can I do this **and** use SSL for all sites? I am really lacking some important keywords I guess, because my google searches did not lead to anything remotely useful...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Let me give you a quick overview so you will be able to get started.

Given your redmine and gitea are running in docker, this setup will proxy incoming requests to your docker hosted backend.

Given you want to use locations this configuration will give you an initial idea. Not tested. It is likely possible that location based proxying will not work as expected with redmine and / or gitea.

From a beginners point of view, having subdomains per service (gitea.myservice.com and redmine.myservice.com) are easier to setup. The certbot configuration will be much easier then.

### Location based (not tested)

```
upstream gita {
  server 127.0.0.1:4100;
}

upstream redmine {
  server 127.0.0.1:4200;
}


server {
  listen 80;
  server_name services.myserver.com;
  

  location /gitea {
    # remove gitea from the URI before sending it to the backend.
    rewrite          ^/gitea(/.*)$ $1 break;

    #use the upstream name to point to your backend.
    proxy_pass http://gitea/;
   

    #More NGINX Proxy directives. Google for NGINX Revers Proxy.
  }
  
  location /redmine {

    # remove gitea from the URI before sending it to the backend.
    rewrite          ^/redmine(/.*)$ $1 break;

    #use the upstream name to point to your backend.
    proxy_pass http://redmine/;
   

    #More NGINX Proxy directives. Google for NGINX Revers Proxy.

  }

}
```

### Subdomains

```
server {
  server_name gitea.myservice.com
  listen 80;

  location / {

   proxy_pass http://gitea/;
   …
  }


}

server {
  server_name redmine.myservice.com
  listen 80;

  location / {

   proxy_pass http://gitea/;
   …
  }


}
```

You can use certbot to create the TLS / SSL configuration. Google for
`certbot setup nginx`

https://certbot.eff.org/lets-encrypt/centosrhel7-nginx

To learn more about how to navigate in the NGINX docs watch my video:
https://youtu.be/nhSYFL1tufM

Have fun running nginx

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! I added the subdomain config. But I cannot startup my nginx because it cannot bind to port 80 (which is probably blocked by seafile's nginx). How can I get the to two coexist?

Comment: personally I would expose the seafile NGINX on port 8080 and use the NGINX instance we are taking about as reverse proxy for all your services running on docker.

Comment: I just realized that I have to have the subdomains registered in order for this method to work. So that means I can only leave cloud.myserver.com for seafile and services.myserver.com/<servicename> for the rest. Now another constraint is that I want to keep the dockered seafile-nginx combination running for cloud.xxx and another nginx instance on the host serving all services.xxx/<servicename> sites. Is this possible somehow? If I just want to start two nginx instances for the two subdomains, I end up with the host nginx not starting up because port 80 and 443 are already in use.

Comment: That will not work on your OS. FreeBSD can do something like that but again I would recommend to use one NGINX Instance as Proxy and forward traffic to your docker containers. Thats a common use case.